# What is the best way to prohibit integer value for Enum action's parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I use some `Enum` as parameter in some action. For example we have the following code

```
public enum SomeEnum { SomeVal1 = 1, SomeVal2 = 2 }

[HttpGet]
public void SomeAction(SomeEnum someParameter) { }
```

By default asp.net engine allows to use both string and integer values that's why we are able to call it like this 'http://host/SomeController/SomeAction/SomeVal1' or this 'http://host/SomeController/SomeAction/1' or even this 'http://host/SomeController/SomeAction/**54**'! I would like to stay with the first sample using string value. For this I've implemented the following model binder:

```
public class RequireStringsAttribute : ModelBinderAttribute
{
    public RequireStringsAttribute() : base(typeof(ModelBinder))
    {

    }

    private class ModelBinder : IModelBinder
    {
        public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {
            var value = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.FieldName).FirstValue;
            var isValid = Enum.GetNames(bindingContext.ModelType).Any(name =>
                name.Equals(value, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
            if (isValid)
            {
                bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(Enum.Parse(bindingContext.ModelType, value, ignoreCase: true));
            }
            else
            {
                bindingContext.ActionContext.ModelState.AddModelError(bindingContext.FieldName, $"The value '{value}' is not valid.");
            }
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
}
```

And I've applied it:

```
[HttpGet]
public void SomeAction([RequireStrings]SomeEnum someParameter) { }
```

It works fine but I just want to know is there a better way to do it?

Comment: I don't think `RequireStrings` is a good name for this attribute, perhaps `RequireDefinedEnumName` is better.